# Observables, how to ignore the last if the next is equals?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, observable

Observables, how to ignore the last if the next is equals?

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingService {
    private _observer: Observer<boolean>;
    loading: Observable<boolean>;
    constructor() {
        this.loading = new Observable<boolean>(
            observer => this._observer = observer);
    }

    toggleLoadingIndicator(isLoading: boolean) {
        if (this._observer) {
            this._observer.next(isLoading);
        }
    }
}
```

And subscribe:

```
loadingService.loading
    .subscribe(isLoading => this.changeLoading(isLoading)
);
```

So, when I call, like this in async:

```
loadingService.toggleLoadingIndicator(true);
setTimeout(() => {
    loadingService.toggleLoadingIndicator(false);
    console.log('finish 5000');
}, 5000);

loadingService.toggleLoadingIndicator(true);
setTimeout(() => {
    loadingService.toggleLoadingIndicator(false); //here turn the indicator false, but it should be true once there is a other call async waiting (the 5000)
    console.log('finish 3000');
}, 3000);
```

When the 3000 finish the indicator turns false. How can I detect if a second true was called in order to cancel the next false and wait for the last one?

Comment: You're looking for distinct until changed: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would consider to use `Subject` (a class from RxJS which compounds an `Observable` and an `Observer`).

Subject has a property `observers` that could be helpful for your requirements, i.e. you could check if the subject/observable has other observers.

Another interesting option is `AsyncSubject` which returns only the last value before closing down (or error in case of error occurence). Also `AsyncSubject` has the method `hasObservers()`.

Last. If you need to implement some sort of control of when different asynchronous operations are completed (e.g. parallel http requests) you can also consider to use the `forkJoin()` method of `Observable` which I find very convenient in such cases (there are several pages on the internet regarding this technique, e.g. http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables)

Comment: I take a look at the Subject and AsyncSubject  but none has the `hasObservers()` method. 

I am using rxjs.

Comment: You are right. I think now the `Subject` / `AyncSubject` have the property `observers`. You can use something like `mySubject.observers.length` to see how many observers there are. I update my answer and hope this helps.